# `<!--:en-->` Language notation in the post content

Tags: tags, translation

Can someone tell mich which plugin usually handles the following notations, used to translate posts?

```
<!--:en-->english text<!--:-->

<!--:es-->spanish text<!--:-->
```

Any way to get the posts translated using these tags is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the notation of the (pretty old) Plugin qtranslate. It was abandoned way back and replaced by mqtranslate and later qtranslate-x, which at this point are also abandoned. You can however convert your content to be used with [wp multilang](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-multilang/), which works with gutenberg, by replacing the `<!--:lang-->` tags with kinda shortcodes [:lang]. So for the english text you would use [:en]English Text[:].

It would be even better if you would put all languages within a post into the same language "shortcodes" instead of "opening" one language, closing it, and "opening" the next language. Like this:

[:en]English Text[:es]Spanish Text[:]

Comment: Exceptional helpful answer there, very appreciated.

Comment: Note: Going with wp_multilang, I didn't had to replace the tags. The content is properly regonized in tabs at the beginning of the panel.

Comment: Huh, didn't notice that. However, i switched to the Bracket-Style when i changed from qtranslate to qtranslate-x ;)